# Assume that $C$ is a compact set and $p\in X\backslash C $.

Tags: general-topology

$(X,d)$ is a metric space.Assume that $C$  is a compact set and $p\in X\backslash C $.
Construct two disjoint open sets $E_1$ and $E_2$ such that $p\in E_1 $ and $C\subset E_2$.

I want to denote $d=d(p,C)$ which $d(p,C)$ is the distance between $p$ and $C$. And $E_1= B(p,\frac{d}{2})$ , $E_2=C$.  I once thought it was figured out. But C is not open ...

So is there any brief construction?

Comment: C can be covered via a finite number open set. If $X$ is Hausdorff, then you can easily construct such $E_1$ and $E_2$. However, topological spaces (indicated by your tag) do not have to support metrics.

Comment: Is $X$ a metric space?  There are some topologies in which this would not be possible.

Comment: @EGoodman It is a metric space.

Comment: Then a hint would be to do it for two points first.  However the answer below is most of what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in C$, define $U_x = B(x,\frac{1}{2}d(x,p)), V_x=B(p,\frac{1}{2}d(x,p))$.

Then $U_x \ \cap \ V_x = \emptyset$, and letting $x$ vary in $C$ we get an open cover $\{U_x\}_{x \in C}$.

Can you take it from here?